# Filtering state data then immediately unfiltered it for next filter call

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks, jsx

I have an interesting use case and I am trying to wrap my head around it.  I have an `array` of `objects` that I use to render table data.  Here are a few elements from the `array`:

```
 [
    {
        Division: "R"
        Fuel: 318
        Hours: "40.00"
        Idle: 367
        MPG: "5.62"
        Miles: 1786
        Name: "INSERT NAME"
        Overtime: "0.37"
        Profit: "3585.54"
        ProfitPerc: "65.37"
        Revenue: "5485.10"
        },
        {
        Division: "L"
        Fuel: 141
        Hours: "40.00"
        Idle: 330
        MPG: "5.91"
        Miles: 833
        Name: "INSERT NAME"
        Overtime: "0.00"
        Profit: "1418.63"
        ProfitPerc: "50.91"
        Revenue: "2786.29"
        },
        {
        Division: "B"
        Fuel: 62
        Hours: "33.73"
        Idle: 143
        MPG: "9.44"
        Miles: 585
        Name: "INSERT NAME"
        Overtime: "0.00"
        Profit: "1055.24"
        ProfitPerc: "53.95"
        Revenue: "1956.02"
        }
    ]
```

What I am trying to do is when a user clicks a specific icon and calls the `filterDivision` `function`, it will `filter` the `array` of `objects` by the `Division` attribute.  Here is what the `JSX` looks like:

```
          <i onClick={(e) => filterDivision("B")} className="fas fa-truck"></i>
          <i
            onClick={(e) => filterDivision("L")}
            class="fas fa-truck-moving"
          ></i>
          <i onClick={(e) => filterDivision("R")} class="fas fa-road"></i>
```

And here is the `filterDivision` `function` so far:

```
 const filterDivision = (arg) => {
    let orig = tableObj;
    setTableObj(orig);
    if (arg) {
      let filtered = tableObj.filter((e) => e["Division"] === arg);
      setTableObj(filtered);
    }
  };
```

What I am trying to do is when the `function` is called, set the `state` to the `filtered` data, then when the `onClick` `function` is fired again, I want to set the original `state` back and `filter` through it.  This way, I can continue to `filter` based off of the three different divisions.

I am setting the state here:

```
const [tableObj, setTableObj] = useState([]);
```

Unfortunately, I can only filter once due to the simple fact that the `tableObj` `state` is missing the drivers we would be hoping to render in the next `filter`.  They were lost when I set the first `filtered` `object` to `state`.

Comment: Why not simply introduce another state variable and call it `filteredTableObj`?

Comment: I could and I thought of that... The only issue is I have multiple sorts already tied in with that initial object.  I guess it's not a big deal to put conditionals to use either/or.  If ````filteredData```` then use, if not use ````tableObj````.  I guess that's the easiest way.

Comment: I'm afraid you'd have to provide a more complete and self-contained code example if you want a better answer.

Comment: If you have to use the previous state, you have to store it in some way. You could try to make your `tableObj` as an object that has the previous and current value, something like `{prev: [], current: []}` and when you call setTableObj move the current to prev like `setTableObj({prev: tableObj.current, current: newArray})`